# Python, opposite of conditional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I have two `numpy` arrays, let's say `A` and `B`

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: A = np.array([0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50])

In [5]: B = np.array([0.15,0.23,0.33,0.41,0.57])
```

I apply a condition like this:

```
In [6]: condition_array = A[(B>0.2)*(B<0.5)]

In [7]: condition_array
Out[7]: array([ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4])
```

**Now how do I get the opposite of `condition_array`?**

i.e. the values of array `A` for which array `B` is **`NOT GREATER THAN 0.2 and NOT LESS THAN 0.5`** ?

```
In [8]: test_array = A[(B<0.2)*(B>0.5)]

In [9]: test_array
Out[9]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

The above doesn't seem to work !

Comment: `NOT GREATER THAN` is the same thing as `LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO` and `NOT LESS THAN` is the same thing as `GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO`

Comment: @EliSadoff: Yes I am aware of that, so what is the solution?

Comment: It's working fine, but there does not exist a value that is both `< 0.2` and `>0.5` which is what your code is asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `~` operator to invert the array ...

```
A[~((B>0.2)*(B<0.5))]
```

Note that your use of `*` seems like it's meant to do a logical "and".  Many people would prefer that you use the binary "and" operator (`&`) instead -- Personally, I prefer to be even more explicit:

```
A[~np.logical_and(B > 0.2, B < 0.5)]
```

Alternatively, the following work too:

```
A[(B <= 0.2) | (B >= 0.5)]
A[np.logical_or(B <= 0.2, B >= 0.5)]
```

Comment: Oh!! What is this sorcery!! I was never aware of the invert operator ! Only the `not` operator seems to be available in the docs, why haven't they mentioned about `~` ? Any idea?

Comment: Python supports a full suite of "bitwise" operators (`|`, `&`, `~`, `^`, `>>`, `<<`).  For builtin types, they're only implemented to work with `int`, `long`.  (Some of the operators work on `set` objects too).  For boolean numpy arrays,  `~`, `|` and `&` are overloaded to perform the logical equivalents -- Otherwise, I think they only work on integer arrays.

Comment: What was the reason you said not to use `*` and instead use `np.logical_and` ? Aren't they the same?

Comment: @ThePredator -- It does the same thing, but when reading the code, if I see a `*`, I don't think of logical "and" so it forces me to step back and try to figure out the expression to get an understanding of what it does.

Answer (score 2):

By [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
A[np.logical_or(~(B > 0.2), ~(B < 0.5)]
```

Or

```
A[np.logical_or(B <= 0.2, B >= 0.5)]
```